# Shopify Django app failing in shopify_app/views.py in finalize

Tags: django, heroku, shopify

I created a Shopify app hosted on Heroku. I had to modify the name of the shopify app from shopify_app to shopifyapp for Heroku to recognize it as a Django app.

If I visit my app directly though app-name.herokuapp/login and connect the app to my store, It correctly pulls my recent orders and products.

If I visit the app through the app menu and it redirects to app-name.herokuapp/login/finalize it shows

KeyError at /login/finalize/

I haven't modified anything in shopify_app except changed it's name to shopifyapp everywhere.

I suspect since the app cant finalize, that is why the links like this also don't work:
https://{{ current_shop.domain }}/admin/orders/{{ order.id }}">{{ order.name }}
They just direct to something like

```
    https://admin/orders/000000000
```

Can anyone help troubleshoot this problem with the shopify app?

I've made my app repo public since it's still essentially just the demo app:
https://github.com/dpetrillo740/scm

App is running at http://scmapp.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the demo App.  I just fixed it with this commit [27d5091](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app/commit/27d5091aa57695bfca4525f55fdf5a09e836ec10).

Update the path in your application url to /login from /login/finalize. The redirect_uri is now provided for authentication with shopify, so it will still redirect back to the finalize endpoint.